# PULP: minimizing the maximum values of a set of vectors

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I have a linear programming problem that I want to solve, with all its data originating in a table.

The table is of size (m * n) and looks something like this:

```
    |    c0      c1       c2       c3      ...       cn        sum
--- + ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ + ------ +++ ----- +
r0  |                                                     |||  Σ r0 
r1  |                                                     |||  Σ r1
r2  |                                                     |||  Σ r2
r3  |                                                     |||  Σ r3
r4  |                                                     |||
 .  |                                                     |||
 .  |                                                     |||
 .  |                                                     |||
rm  |                                                     |||  Σ rm
------------------------------------------------------------------- +
max |max(c0)  max(c1)  max(c2)  max(c3)           max(cn) |||  Σ max(c0...n)
```

All bins in this table will hold a float value when the problem has been optimized.

I'm trying to minimize the **sum of the maximums** of each column **(Σ max(c0...n))**.

I have created an `LpProblem`:

```
problem = pulp.LpProblem("problem",pulp.LpMinimize)
```

I have created `LpVariables` representing each bin in the table:

```
variables = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("bin",
                                  ((r,c) for r in rows for c in columns),
                                  lowBound=0,
                                  cat='Continuous')
```

I know the sums of each row beforehand (**Σ rx**), and a constraint is that a row **x**'s values must sum to **Σ rx**. As a feature of these data, only a subset of indices in a row can contribute to this Σ rx value. For example, only bins (0,1) and (0,3) in row 0 will potentially have non-zero values. The index of these contributing bins differs from row to row; some rows may only have 1 contributing bin, while other rows have multiple (or all) contributing bins. I've accounted for this by creating constraints for each row.

```
for row in rows:
    column_set # a list of bin indexes for this row that make up the sum.
    variable_set = [ variables[(row,c)] for c in column_set ]
    problem += pulp.lpSum(variable_set) == row_sum # the sum of the row.
```

My issue lies in how to define my objective function. Since python's `max()` doesn't work on `LpVariable` objects, I trying to think of how to get the max value of any column and assign that to its own `LpVariable` object.

One way of doing that may be to loop through each `LpVariable` representing bins in a given column, do something like `v = variable.value()` and add all `v`s to a list, then do `max()` on this list and set an `LpVariable` equal to that, but this only gets the initial value of the `LpVariable`s, and as the solver changes data around during the `solve()` process, these max values will not be updated dynamically.

I've also tried making separate `LpVariable`s representing each column's max, setting them up like this:

```
pulp.LpVariable("Max___{}".format(s),
                lowBound=max([v.value() for v in column]),
                upBound=max([v.value() for v in column]),
                cat=pulp.LpContinuous
               )
```

but again this seems like just taking the values from the initial conditions of each `LpVariable`, and running `solve()` on this returns an `'infeasible'` solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

A **high-level description**:

- `m rows, n cols`
- introduce `n` new *continuous variables* `m_0, m_1, ..., m_(n-1)`
- add `m*n` new *constraints* of the form:

  - `m_0 >= entry(r_0,c_0)`
  - `m_0 >= entry(r_1,c_0)`
  - ...
  - `m_0 >= entry(r_(m-1),c_0)`
  - ...
  - ...
  - `m_1 >= entry(r_0,c_1)`
  - `m_1 >= entry(r_1,c_1)`
  - ...
  - `m_1 >= entry(r_(m-1),c_1)`
  - ...
- *objective*:

  - `minimize(m_0 + m_1 + ... + m_(n-1))`

**Remarks**:

- this only works if each m is somehow pushed down by the solver!

  - here: minimize the sum -> ok!
- it's independent on the type of the entries (binary, integer, continuous)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the sparsity of this problem in an easier way, by defining a set of 2-member tuples that are the row-column indexes of possible non-zero entries in the table.

To handle the max entry in each column, introduce new decision variables and constraints as @sascha had mentioned.

For example:

```
"""
Example where the table is 2x2, and any entries can be non-zero except the (2,1) entry
"""

import pulp

# Define the sparse set of row-column indexes for entries that can be non-zero
rowCols = set([(1, 1),
               (1, 2),
               (2, 2)])

# Define row sums
rowSums = {1: 1.1,
           2: 3.4}

# Detect the rows and columns of the table
rows = set([row for (row, _) in rowCols])
cols = set([col for (_, col) in rowCols])

# Define the PuLP model
problem = pulp.LpProblem("problem", pulp.LpMinimize)

# Define the variables
variables = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("bin", rowCols, lowBound=0,
                                  cat=pulp.LpContinuous)
colMaxes = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("maximum entry in the column", cols,
                                 lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

# Define the constraints
#  row sum
for row in rows:
    problem += (
        pulp.lpSum([variables[row, col]
                    for col in cols
                    if (row, col) in rowCols])
        ==
        rowSums[row]
    )
#  max in column
for (row, col) in rowCols:
    problem += (
        pulp.lpSum([variables[row1, col1]
                    for (row1, col1) in rowCols
                    if col1 == col])
        <=
        colMaxes[col]
    )

# Define objective function
problem += pulp.lpSum([colMaxes[col] for col in cols])

# Solve the problem
problem.solve()

# Print the solution
print('row col value')
for (row, col) in rowCols:
    print(row, col, variables[row, col].varValue)
```