# Optimization to minimize the difference between the zero crossings of several vectors by moving values freely between another set of vectors

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am having trouble formulating an optimization problem for which I need to minimize the difference between the median values of several vectors by moving values freely between another vector.
The example below involves only 2 datasets for now and is structured as followed:

```
Ds1 = [[60, -20],
[65, -10],
[70, -5],
[75,-3],
[80,5],
[85,10],
[90,15],
[95,20]]

Ds2 = [[70, -20],
[75,-10],
[80,-5],
[85,-3],
[90, 5],
[95, 10],
[100, 15],
[105,20]]
```

I want to minimize the difference between the value of column 1 where column 2 crosses from negative to positive between datasets. So, for Ds1 this would be 77.5 and for Ds2 87.5 and the absolute difference here is 10. The basic idea is I can move x number of units from column 2 in each set by adding or subtracting into column 2 to/from the other dataset. So, for example let’s say I moved 5 units from Ds1 column 2 to Ds2 column 2, the resulting data sets would look like the below:

```
Ds1 = [[60, -25],
[65, -15],
[70, -10],
[75,-8],
[80,0],
[85,5],
[90,10],
[95,15]]

Ds2 = [[70, -15],
[75,-5],
[80,0],
[85,2],
[90, 10],
[95, 15],
[100, 20],
[105,25]]
```

This results crossing values for each dataset being 80 (as column 2 crosses over 0 at exactly the that point.)
I want to formulate a mixed integer optimization problem that tracks the amount being added or subtracted between each data set, as well as the “mid point” value for column 1. I thought I might be able to model this problem as a version of the traveling sales person problem as done here in this post:

https://towardsdatascience.com/a-mixed-integer-optimization-approach-to-rebalancing-a-bike-sharing-system-48d5ad0898bd
But given my rebalance values are vectors and not single values I’m struggling how to formulate this since there is no way to get the mid value of a variable in an optimization problem.
Additionally, my issue is somewhat related to this post:

[PULP: minimizing the maximum values of a set of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920429/pulp-minimizing-the-maximum-values-of-a-set-of-vectors)

but given my objective is based on a different vectors or value within a vector, my full formulation seems like it needs to be a combination of the two.
Any help or comments you have for this would be very helpful.

Comment: I must say, the way you've explained the problem was quite confusing, particularly paragraphs 2 & 3. First you were explaining how you were trying to match the median of the first columns, then you did something and the goal changed to finding zero-crossings on the second columns to map to the first... Clarification would be nice.

My suggestion would be to look for another perspective into this problem. Can you represent this data in any other format? For example, maybe there is a geometric representation that makes it very clear how to approach the problem.

Comment: I've edited the wording to be a bit more clear. I am trying the match the zero crossings. And yes a different perspective would be good but I'm struggling to do so obviously.

Comment: How do you know where one "line" crosses zero?  The points you gave are *almost* linear, which would have made this much easier.  Are you just "connecting" point-to-point?  If so, is there any guarantee that the sign of the slope remains the same?  Inflections would make this more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but here's my alternative perspective of the problem which you might find useful. Since it's quite long, I've had to write it as an answer. Note that I've had to make some assumptions about the problem.

**Assumptions:**

1. Both columns in all datasets are sorted (the direction doesn't matter)
2. When the crossing point crosses between two points, you take the median value `(a1+a2)/2` and not the linearly interpolated value. E.g. if you have two points, `0` and `100`, the middle point will always be `50`, no matter where the zero crossing line gets to either value.
3. The only valid configurations are ones where the zero crossing line is "within the bounds" of each dataset.

---

First, I tried playing with just 2 datasets.

I tried plotting each series out as a scatter plot, imagining them as a set of xy coordinates. Since you are changing `column 2` to "indirectly affect" `column 1`, I've imagined `column 2` as the X-axis, and `column 1` as the Y-axis. Here is the plot:

[image: Scatter Plot]

Your goal here is to "move" each line left-right, until they intersect each other, at the zero crossing line. *(This is analogous to you trying to get the same middle value; both datasets always meet at the same xy value.)*

The catch is that moving one line in one direction, will also move the other line in the opposite direction, with the exact same distance. *(This part is analogous to "moving values" between the two right columns, adding from one must subtract from the other, and vice-versa).*

When I put it in this perspective, and if the assumptions are correct, then this simplified problem seems trivial. You can just keep "sliding" one line until it intersects the other at the middle. Imagine first moving the red line until it is fully on the right half of the zero crossing, then slowly moving it back towards the left.

[image]

For 2 datasets, this should be trivial to brute force, as you can check all possible combinations. (By defining valid positions as one where each dataset still touches the zero crossing line, thus confining the problem to a finite space.)

---

But once things go beyond 2 datasets... it gets complicated.

To attempt anything beyond this, I think you need to properly define your fitness function. For a simple case (this is your example) you can draw an optimization landscape like this.

[image]

For more than 2 datasets, I'd imagine it would become a multidimensional landscape. Depending on the landscape, you might get away with simple search algorithms like [hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing). But if the landscape turns out to be [hard to search](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/projects/ecb/displayDataset.php?id=8)... *then I hope you're not looking to get the optimal solution :)*

---

Please note that I find the original problem still too poorly defined to attempt. Here are some of the questions I have:

- How do other datasets change when you modify one? Do you choose which one you "transfer" the points to? Or are they distributed evenly?
- How do you calculate the "distance" for multiple datasets? Total distance between all pairs? Minimum / Maximum distance of any pair? Etc.
- What happens if you move one dataset, such that the zero crossing line no longer "touches" it. Is this a valid configuration? If valid, what is the "middle" value for this set?

Comment: Excellent response, thank you for your detail! All of your assumptions are correct. I like the brut force attempt you've done but as you've surmised, I would indeed need to have more than 2 lines. To answer your questions:
- nothing changes with handling of datasets when adding in more. anything that moves into one dataset must move out of the other. One thing to note it can only move to one dataset and not through and into another.
-there is no need for distance calculation and there is no cost.
-if the zero crossing no longer touches then a min or max value is used.

Comment: I have created a sort of solution in excel using solver(that i cant post here). I've created a binary variable to track the zero crossing then get the x value from there and minimize the diff between the 2. The decision variables are the numbers to be added/subtracted or going to and from)the datasets ( and also some aux variables for making the problem linear, i.e. to minimize the abs diff between the x where zero crossing is found). Not sure how robust this is but it seems to do the trick. My only issue is coding it into python.

Comment: When I work on problems like these, I can recommend two things. **Select a good representation of your data**; it's even more important than finding a good solver. Common python tools like [scikit-learn](https://scikit-optimize.github.io) depends on this. Second is to **start simple** when programming. I usually write out my logic on paper first, then try to code it. Since you've already done it in excel, I think you're more than half way there. For ref, my fitness function was written using simple if-else logic to find zero crossing that just works. I'll share you my MATLAB code later today.

Comment: @CrystalCarreon [Here's the code](https://pastebin.com/fRMGBDP6) I used for the fitness function. Although it's in MATLAB and not python, it should be simple enough to understand. I hope this helps with your coding. Good luck!